# How to shorten SSRS Subscription Email URL?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

The URL received in SSRS Subscription Email contains all the parameters selected. Like below,

The report is accessible at the following address:

http://bi-gateway/ReportServer?%2FAttendance%2FAttendance_Daily_Late&LineManager=NAME_1&LineManager=NAME_2&LineManager=NAME_3&LineManager=NAME_3&LineManager=NAME_4&rs%3AParameterLanguage=en-US

I need this URL to be short. So, is there a way in SSRS that this URL can be shortened.

Comment: what about using a url generator like tiny url?

Comment: I can make a url shortener in Python. But I want to know if there's a way to do it in SSRS